# Can connect to remote database through MySQL Workbench, but not Java JBDC

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I have a remote MySQL database that I can connect to with MySQL Workbench (screen shot below), but I ultimately need to connect to it via JBDC and everytime I try to connect, it throws an exception.  I'm new to this, so could anyone provide me some insight on what could be wrong?

```
String host = "testdb.db.10682960.hostedresource.com";
String datab = "testdb";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + datab;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, datab, "password");
```

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

[image: MySQL Workbench Connection]

Edit: Not sure if this is relevant or not, but I'm running this on Android.

Comment: hello matt..without jdbc driver connection with mysql in android is also possible...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a user name.  Try adding "?user=testdb" to the end of your url.

Edit: I didn't realize this was an Android app.  Technically, it should be possible, but not advisable.  Your network connection would be much less reliable, and you would be pushing server credentials out to your client.  Use of a REST API to communicate from your Android to a web server in the same data center as the database is a much safer option.

I don't have experience trying this from Android... so I don't know what exception would be thrown if, for example, you can't reach port 3306 from the Android's connection to the network.  Even if you get it working, though, do look into using a web service instead.

Comment: Tried changing the url to `String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/?user=" + datab;` but still same exception

Comment: Your datab and user happen to have the same name.  Your url needs to contain both.

Comment: Try: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + datab + "?user=testdb";`

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it's still not working.  I added an edit to clarify that I'm running on Android if that makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah... that makes a difference.  Even if it were possible, it would be ill-advised both for security reasons (you push your credentials out to the client where they can be inspected) and a variety of network-related reasons (stability and NAT firewalls, e.g.).  Front-end your database with a web service and talk to that from your Android.

Comment: Ok, my apologies.  From doing a little research, it looks like I can create a php front-end connection to the MySQL database to retrieve data that my App can then invoke through AndroidHttpClient.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jTDS FAQ (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) the format of a JDBC URL is:

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

If I were you, I would replace the '?' with a ';' to adhere to the above format. The "query string" is not like that of a "normal" URL.

This, of course, assumes that you are using the open source JDBC connector found via the link above.